# Problem with $_FILES and cURL

Tags: php, http, file, curl

I'm having some trouble sending $_FILES by cURL - the files get transferred alright using the following code, however it is impossible for me to get the name, and type of the file, in fact once the $_FILES reach their destination their type is stored as "application/octet-stream" - what am I doing wrong!?

```
 $count=count($_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name']);

 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
  if(!empty($_FILES['thefile']['name'][$i])) {
   $postargs[$i] = '@'.$_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'][$i];
  }
 }


 $header = array("Content-type: multipart/form-data");
 $ch = curl_init('http://localhost/curl/rec.php');
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");  
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false); 
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postargs);
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your should construct $postargs like this,

```
 $postargs = array();
 foreach ($_FILES as $param => $file) {
     $postargs[$param] = '@' . $file['tmp_name'] . ';filename=' . $file['name'] . ';type=' . $file['type'];
 }
```